How to interpret escape characters in a string and display them as newlines, color etc
i grep something like:
str='"a\nb"'
echo ${str} | grep -E -o '".*"'

and got:
"a\nb"

i wish the result displays like:
a
b

how could this be done? thanks
p.s. actually, the str is
str='"\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\33[32m[58,378 / 59,145]\33[0m 12 actions running\n    Compiling interface/detail/type_support.c; 5s linux-sandbox\n    Compiling interface/detail/type_c.cpp; 5s linux-sandbox\n    ; 2s linux-sandbox ...\n"'

i think the \33[...part is related to color on shell, which is more complicated...could the \n  and  \r as well as color display as human-readable by grep or jq?

If you are working with JSON data, then grep is not the tool for the job.  Instead, you'd use a JSON parser like jq, which also would be able to decode the encoded JSON string, which would output a literal newline rather than the quoted and encoded value.

thanks @Kusalananda, case is im not handling json...just some plain text as shown...

So what do you want to get as output from that string? Your string doesn't contain newline characters, it contains \  followed by a n, \  followed by an r etc. Are you trying to convert that to a real newline or carriage return character?

If you want to interpret backslash-escapes, the command to do that is printf %b "$str". But you may want to be careful before dumping unknown escape codes to a terminal.

You showed what your real str is but you didn't show your attempted grep command for your real str nor your expected output given that str as input.

I suggest editing the question, as it doesn't have anything to do with grep. The real question is how to interpret escape codes in the given input (which happens to be grep's output, but wouldn't have to be).

I suspect your problems probably start with how str is being populated. It's odd to have a variable looking like that and it usually means you're doing something wrong in how you're populating the variable (e.g. maybe it should be an array instead of scalar, or maybe you're reading output of a command incorrectly, or using a shell while-read loop undesirably, or cat-ing a file into a variable, or ....). If you show a minimal, complete script showing how that variable is populated along with concise, testable sample input and expected output we can help you.

While "a\nb" would have been both a valid JSON or C language string representation,
"\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\r\33[1A\33[K\33[32m[58,378 / 59,145]\33[0m 12 actions running\n    Compiling interface/detail/type_support.c; 5s linux-sandbox\n    Compiling interface/detail/type_c.cpp; 5s linux-sandbox\n    ; 2s linux-sandbox ...\n"

Would not be valid JSON¹ but could still be a representation of a string in the C programming language where \33 is the representation of byte value 27 (033 in octal) which on most systems is the encoding of the ESC control character, \n of the newline (aka linefeed/LF) character (byte 10 on ASCII-based systems, YMMV on other systems, though those are quite rare these days).
C strings are enclosed in " and a " within can be represented as \" or as \42 (or \042) on ASCII-based systems. \ as \\, ' either as ' or \', ? wither as ? or \? and a number of other escape sequences for control characters beside \n are recognised. In recent versions of the C language, hexadecimal can also be used in place of octal with \xff  or \x00000000ff representing byte 255 (like \377) for instance, and \uxxxx / \Uxxxxxxxx can be used to represent the UTF-8 encoding of the character with corresponding Unicode code point.
For instance, this C code:
#include <stdio.h>
char *str = "a\'\?b\
c\nd\u00e9\x0005c";

int main() {
  puts(str);
  return 0;
}

When compiled and run in a UTF-8 locale prints:
a'?bc
dé\

In some versions of the C language, some characters (that a long time ago were not always found in all encodings) can be represented with trigraphs.
In the POSIX shell and utilities, the format argument of printf and the $'...' form of quotes² support something approaching (not trigraphs, not \', not line continuation nor \x/\u/\U for printf though many printf implementations support those as an extension though generally not in the exact same way).
You can output a C string like a C compiler would decode it provided there's no \", \', \?, \u..., \U..., \x..., trigraphs nor line continuations and the string is valid UTF-8 and your locale has UTF-8 as its charmap by:

removing the leading and trailing ".
replacing % with %%

And pass the resulting string to printf --:
In a ksh93-like shell such as ksh93, zsh, bash or mksh, that could be done with:
str=${str#\"} # remove leading "
str=${str%\"} # remove trailing "
str=${str//[%]/%%} # replace all % with %%
printf -- "$str" # pass to printf for it to interpret the \... sequences
                 # in a C-like fashion

With your particular value of $str, that gives:
$ zsh ./that-code | od -vtu1 -tc
0000000  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75
         \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K  \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K
0000020  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75
         \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K  \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K
0000040  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75
         \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K  \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K
0000060  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75
         \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K  \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K
0000100  13  27  91  49  65  27  91  75  27  91  51  50 109  91  53  56
         \r 033   [   1   A 033   [   K 033   [   3   2   m   [   5   8
0000120  44  51  55  56  32  47  32  53  57  44  49  52  53  93  27  91
          ,   3   7   8       /       5   9   ,   1   4   5   ] 033   [
0000140  48 109  32  49  50  32  97  99 116 105 111 110 115  32 114 117
          0   m       1   2       a   c   t   i   o   n   s       r   u
0000160 110 110 105 110 103  10  32  32  32  32  67 111 109 112 105 108
          n   n   i   n   g  \n                   C   o   m   p   i   l
0000200 105 110 103  32 105 110 116 101 114 102  97  99 101  47 100 101
          i   n   g       i   n   t   e   r   f   a   c   e   /   d   e
0000220 116  97 105 108  47 116 121 112 101  95 115 117 112 112 111 114
          t   a   i   l   /   t   y   p   e   _   s   u   p   p   o   r
0000240 116  46  99  59  32  53 115  32 108 105 110 117 120  45 115  97
          t   .   c   ;       5   s       l   i   n   u   x   -   s   a
0000260 110 100  98 111 120  10  32  32  32  32  67 111 109 112 105 108
          n   d   b   o   x  \n                   C   o   m   p   i   l
0000300 105 110 103  32 105 110 116 101 114 102  97  99 101  47 100 101
          i   n   g       i   n   t   e   r   f   a   c   e   /   d   e
0000320 116  97 105 108  47 116 121 112 101  95  99  46  99 112 112  59
          t   a   i   l   /   t   y   p   e   _   c   .   c   p   p   ;
0000340  32  53 115  32 108 105 110 117 120  45 115  97 110 100  98 111
              5   s       l   i   n   u   x   -   s   a   n   d   b   o
0000360 120  10  32  32  32  32  59  32  50 115  32 108 105 110 117 120
          x  \n                   ;       2   s       l   i   n   u   x
0000400  45 115  97 110 100  98 111 120  32  46  46  46  10
          -   s   a   n   d   b   o   x       .   .   .  \n
0000415

Where od is used to show us the byte values in the output of printf. You see that \33 has been changed into byte 27, \n into byte 10.
Now, if instead of piping to od, we had let that output go straight to a terminal device file, and there was a terminal at the other end receiving that output, those control characters would have been interpreted by the terminal.
For instance, the \r control character causes the cursor to go back to the first column, \n causes it to go down¹, \e[1A on most terminals, like \e[A makes it go up, \e[K makes it clear everything from the cursor to the right end of the screen, \e[32m changes the foreground colour to green, etc.
After sending that output to a terminal (by removing the | od...) and after running seq 12, on the screen I see:
$ seq 12; zsh ./that-code
1
2
3
[58,378 / 59,145] 12 actions running
    Compiling interface/detail/type_support.c; 5s linux-sandbox
    Compiling interface/detail/type_c.cpp; 5s linux-sandbox
    ; 2s linux-sandbox ...

With [58,378 / 59,145] in green. See also how it has overwritten the last 9 lines of the output of seq as it has moved the cursor up as many times.
If you wanted to get just that text and feed it to grep, you'd need to send it to a terminal (of the type it was intended for) and request that terminal the result of its rendering. As it happens, all the escape sequences in your sample are supported by the GNU screen terminal emulator and that terminal emulator supports dumping its screen contents so you could use the approach described at How to convert escape sequences to text while preserving display format?.

² JSON strings are strings of characters, not bytes, where the ESC character would be represented as \u001b, not \33 and there are several other incompatibilities between JSON and C string representations.
² Only added to the 2024 edition of the POSIX specification, so not all sh implementations support it yet.
³ Though note that the terminal device driver can be told (and is generally being told by default) to translate those \n to \r\n before sending it to the terminal which is how \n is usually rendered as the line delimiter it is meant to be on Unix.

echo -e 'a\nb' | grep -E ".*" worked for me.
From the echo manpage

-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes


You seem to have forgotten the double quotes that were part of the initial string.

thanks, but my case is not about echo, the echo part is just a demo for grep ;)

@furynerd Well, the grep isn't really doing very much...

@Kusalananda that is true, however with the double quotes it would also output them in the output

but if the double-quotes are there in the source, and you pass it through echo -e and then grep for ".*" as in the question, it won't match quoted strings that have a newline since the quotes won't be on the same line any more. i.e. echo -e '"a\nb"' | grep -E '".*"' prints nothing

If you need arguments to echo (e.g. -e or -n) then you should be using printf instead, see why-is-printf-better-than-echo.

@EdMorton That question, and the accepted answer, are the actual answer to this question. Basically, printf '%b\n' '"a\nb"' should be used, with eg. tr -d \" to also remove quotation marks.
